# Convert string with spaces to html url in python 3.3

Tags: python, parsing, url, python-3.3

I'm trying to convert a YQL string with spaces to html code.

Here's the YQL string I'm using:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in ("MSFT", "AAPL") and startDate = "2010-10-01" and endDate = "2010-10-05"
```

Here's the url code that needs to come out:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22MSFT%22%2C%20%22AAPL%22)%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222010-10-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222010-10-05%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=
```

I've been trying to do this with *urllib.parse.urlencode* but have not had any luck.

I can get up to "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" but afterwards it starts to break down. Is there a pythonesque way to do this that I'm just missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
import urllib

url_start = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q="
url_end = "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback="
```

you can encode the string as a dict like this:

```
d = {'select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in ("MSFT", "AAPL") and startDate':'"2010-10-01"', 'and endDate':'"2010-10-05"'}

encode_url = urllib.urlencode(d)

#output is:
'select+%2A+from+yahoo.finance.historicaldata+where+symbol+in+%28%22MSFT%22%2C+%22AAPL%22%29+and+startDate=%222010-10-01%22&and+endDate=%222010-10-05%22'

url = url_start + encode_url + url_end
```

Comment: [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) is a package with nothing in it in Python 3.x. You probably want [`urllib.parse`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).

Comment: I don't think this works. I tried combining your three strings and the page gives an error. The URL I provide gives actual data.

Comment: I think abarnet is right. It seems urllib was split into parts for python3.x, and I wasn't aware. However, if urllib.parse has a urlencode method, that should do the same job, if applied like above.. quote_plus method also might work with urllib.parse, I would try that.

Comment: As I mentioned above. If I copy your three string outputs into one large string, that still doesn't work, so I don't think it's a urllib.parse issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.quote('http://www.example.com/déjà-vu/example two.html')
'http%3A//www.example.com/d%C3%A9j%C3%A0-vu/example%20two.html'
```